# "End of script output before headers" in Apache + PHP

Tags: php, apache, cgi, file-permissions

***UPDATE:*** *This issue was caused by the server request timing out before the script completed.**

I have legacy code running on a shared LAMP host (nearlyfreespeech.net), and I recently added a new script that refuses to work in production.

My apache error logs show the message `End of script output before headers: switch.php`, and I get 500 statuses when trying to trigger the script with a web client.

According to other StackOverflow posts, this error message is usually due to a file permissions error. However, the file permissions on the new script are the same as all the others.

Here are the relevant file permissions:

```sh
-rw-rw-r--   1 235430  235430  1655 Jul  6 18:05 switch.php

drwxrwxr-x   2 235430  235430    18 Jul  1 21:05 auth/
-rw-rw-r--  1 235430  235430     13 Aug 24  2015 auth/.htaccess
-rw-rw-r--  1 235430  235430    280 Jul  1 21:05 auth/cloudsaves.2.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 235430  235430    880 Aug 28  2015 auth/cloudsaves.php
-rw-r--r--  1 235430  web     15580 Jul  1 21:05 auth/rumpus_migration.php
```

With these `include()` heirarchies:

- `switch.php -> auth/cloudsaves.php` (works)
- `switch.php -> auth/cloudsaves.2.php <- auth/rumpus_migration.php` (does not work)

**All requests are for `switch.php`** and include a parameter value causing either `auth/cloudsaves.php` or `auth/cloudsaves.2.php` to be included.

In my local test environment everything works just fine. In production when I use the parameter that causes `switch.php` to include the `cloudsaves.2.php` script I get the error.

I've tried changing the group and permissions on `rumpus_migration.php` and `cloudsaves.2.php` to exactly match other files that are properly being included by the parent `switch.php` script, always with the same outcome. This new script (`cloudsaves.2.php`) is the only script included by `switch.php` that itself `includes` another script.

I'm not familiar with Apache or PHP, and the production code is on a shared host where I have extremely limited admin access. The fact that the code works locally but not in production makes it seem that a permissions issue is a likely culprit, but I don't know how to move forward since none of the working permissions options seem to fix it.

Comment: Try replacing `cloudsaves.2.php` with a dummy file, see if the problem persists, to eliminate the possibility that it's a code issue.

Comment: @MarkusAO Thanks, I just finished doing exactly this and confirmed that it is a code issue. Posting an answer shortly.

Comment: I just want to add that I encountered the same error while using a dummy PHP script to test my CGI configuration on a new OS & Apache install. The script had the correct permissions, but I was still getting the nondescript `End of script output before headers` error in the log. The problem ended up being very obvious in hindsight: `php` was not installed on this new machine yet. Point is, don't overlook the obvious steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was that the request was timing out before the script completed, due to a long-running database query.

So that generic `End of script output before headers` error can be caused by server timeouts as well as file permissions issues.

Comment: Thanks for following up, glad you got it sorted.